# When clicking on a text, how do I navigate to an image of the slider that is associated with that text?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, foreach, slider

```
@foreach (var item in Model.NewsList)
            {
                if (item.Title != null)
                {
                    var ImagePathLarge = item.ImagePathWithoutExtension + "/" + item.ImageNameWithoutExtension + "_large" + item.Extension;
                    var ImagePathSmall = item.ImagePathWithoutExtension + "/" + item.ImageNameWithoutExtension + "_small" + item.Extension;

                    <div class='@(i != 0 ? "hidden" : "") vertical-rotator-min active col-item-vertical-rotator-@Model.ModuleInstanceId'>
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="vertical-rotator-desk">
                            <!-- vertical rotator image -->
                            <div class="col-md-8 no-padding col-vertical-rotator-image-@Model.ModuleInstanceId">
                                <div class="vertical-rotator-fix-img">
                                    <div style="background-image:url('@ImagePathLarge')" class="img-size-sb"></div>
                                    <p class="description-vertical-rotator-text">@item.ShortDescription</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            @foreach (var descriptionList in Model.NewsList)
                            {
                               
                                      <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <!-- vertical rotator image -->
                                          <div class="col-md-4 col-vertical-rotator-text-@Model.ModuleInstanceId dsc-vertical-rotator">
                                              <div class="fix-vertical-rotator">
                                                  <p class="description-vertical-rotator">@descriptionList.ShortDescription</p>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                i++;
            }

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const textElements = document.querySelectorAll(".description-vertical-rotator");
    const sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".img-size-sb");

    textElements.forEach((textElement, index) => {
        textElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (sliderImages[index]) {
                // Hide all slider images
                sliderImages.forEach((image) => {
                    image.style.display = "none";
                });

                // Display the corresponding image
                sliderImages[index].style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I created a div that contains the image on the right side and on the left side is the text, I can't however make it so when I click the text it navigates me to the associated image in the vertical slider, I also added the javascript code I used but I don't see the problem here, or maybe it is because of the divs that I used in javascript

Comment: did you try `onclick` event handler or `<a href="your path to image"></a>`?

Comment: I even tried with addEventListener but so far nothing is working

Comment: at its current state your code does not look like it should have any navigation at all. please update it so we could see what exactly does not work for you

Comment: @YehorAndrosov I updated the code, now it needs navigation

Comment: there is still no 'onclick', 'a' tag, or 'addEventListener' in the code

Comment: that's why I'm asking how the javascript should be done

Comment: i've answered "how" in my first comment and then you provided the other correct answer yourself as well. my current struggle is to understand what does not work for you in the approach you chose

Comment: @YehorAndrosov I added the javascript code as well, I don't see the problem if I want to click on the text and it should navigate me to the associated image in slider

Comment: it is hard to understand how it should work because css is missing, but here some ideas.  "description-vertical-rotator" is inside nested `Model.NewsList` loop. It means if there are 4 news items, there will be 4^2=16 "description-vertical-rotator". this seems to break javascript because "index" does not take that into account. I tried to make a small example using JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/yehorandrosov/ajnu9e1h/29/
In this structure number of images and "buttons" matches, so clicking on button works

Comment: @YehorAndrosov this actually helped me solve the problem!!thank you